# Run Function On N Elements of Array at a Time

Tags: arrays, perl

Let's say I have an array `my @arr` which is of hypothetical length 240 (but this length is variable).  How could I go about running a function on each N elements of that array at a time?

For example, if `N = 100`, the function would first run on `@arr[0..99]`, then `@arr[100..199]`, and finally `@arr[200..239]`.

My idea was to have some sort of loop which creates a temporary array of length N by joining N elements together, but these seems overly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while (@arr) {
   f(splice(@arr, 0, 100));
}
```

Non-destructive version:

```
use List::Util qw( min );

for (my $i=0; $i<@a; $i+=100) {
   f(@arr[$i .. min($i+99, $#arr)]);
}
```

You could also avoid destroying the original array cheaply by creating an array of aliases:

```
my $shadow = sub { \@_ }->(@arr);
while (@$shadow) {
   f(splice(@$shadow, 0, 100));
}
```

Comment: Great non-destructive and simple solution with min.  The `min` element was the piece I was missing, and this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`splice`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html):

```
sub apply_f_to_n_elements {
   my ($f, $n, @elements) = @_;

   my @results;
   while ( @elements ) {
      my @batch = splice(@elements, 0, $n)
      push @results,
         $f->(@batch);
   }

   return @results;
}
```

Usage:

```
apply_f_to_n_elements(\&f, 100, @arr);
```

or

```
my @results = apply_f_to_n_elements(\&f, 100, @arr);
```

---

The following is optimized to avoid making two copies of every input (while still remaining non-destructive), and optimized to avoid collecting the results of the callback if they're going to be discarded anyway:

```
sub apply_f_to_n_elements {
   my $f = shift;
   my $n = shift;

   if (wantarray) {    
      my @results;
      while (@_) {
         push @results, $f->(splice(@_, 0, $n));
      }
      return @results;
   } else {
      while (@_) {
         $f->(splice(@_, 0, $n));
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That wasn't really the point of my comment, but yes the original array will still have values.

Comment: Interesting approach, but I actually need a non-destructive approach for what I'm doing.  @ikegami has an approach that does that.

Comment: @JasonBrooks The array here is copied locally when the procedure is called, so your original array is not destroyed; only the local copy.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`List::Util qw(min)`](http://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html) works well.

However, if you want a more semantic solution, you can use [`List::MoreUtils qw(natatime)`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List%3a%3aMoreUtils).

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(natatime);

my $iter = natatime 100, @arr;
while (my @vals = $iter->()) {
    f(@vals);
}
```